# Evaluating $\int \cot^3 x\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

Recently I tried to evaluate
$$\int \cot^3 x\,\mathrm dx$$
but did not find any way to do it. Is it possible, and if it is can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: It's $-\ln\left(\left|\sin\left(x\right)\right|\right)-\dfrac{\cot^2\left(x\right)}{2}$. You can see the steps, if you derivate.

Comment: hint: $x=\text{arccot}(y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: try rewriting $\cot^3x$ as $\cot x(\csc^2x-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int (\cot^3x+\cot x-\cot x)dx=-\int -(1+\cot^2x)\cot x\,dx-\int \cot x dx$$
we have
$$\int \cot x\,dx=\ln|\sin x|+C$$
and
$$\int -(1+\cot^2x)\cot x\,dx=\frac 12 \cot^2x+C$$
therefore
$$I=-\frac 12 \cot^2x-\ln|\sin x|+C$$